# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object with def __str__(self): when I delete the inline form object

Tags: python, django, admin, inline

I am encountering a maximum recursion depth exceeded...error when I try to delete one of the inline forms in Django admin.

This is my model:

```py
class Correction_Factors(models.Model):
    
    Treatment_unit= models.ManyToManyField(Unit,blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):   
        return u", ".join([a.name for a in self.Treatment_unit.all()])
```

It seems to be the problem is in `self.Treatment_unit.all()`. No errors occurred while the inline form is created. It has only come up as soon as I started to delete one of the inline forms.
I tried to switch to `def __Unicode__(self):` but it did not return what I expect. The returned text appeared like "Correction_Factors object (23)" with no details.

N.B. There is no delation issue with `def __Unicode__(self):`. And I am on Django 2.2.18 and python 3.9.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcGOp.png)

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/output/dosimetry_system/18/change/

Django Version: 2.2.18
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django_extensions',
 'django_q',
 'django_comments',
 'formtools',
 'django_filters',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_filters',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'listable',
 'genericdropdown',
 'recurrence',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'dynamic_raw_id',
 'mptt',
 'django_mptt_admin',
 'qatrack.cache',
 'qatrack.accounts',
 'qatrack.units',
 'qatrack.qa',
 'qatrack.qatrack_core',
 'qatrack.notifications',
 'qatrack.contacts',
 'qatrack.issue_tracker',
 'qatrack.service_log',
 'qatrack.parts',
 'qatrack.faults',
 'qatrack.attachments',
 'qatrack.reports',
 'admin_views',
 'qatrack.output',
 'simple_history']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'qatrack.middleware.login_required.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
 'qatrack.middleware.maintain_filters.FilterPersistMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1648.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1529.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1574.                 change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets, add)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in construct_change_message
  1050.         return construct_change_message(form, formsets, add)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in construct_change_message
  520.                             'object': str(deleted_object),

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  527.         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
  838.                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '

File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __repr__
  519.         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)

File "H:\Python projects\deploy\qatrackplus\qatrack\output\models.py" in __str__
  207.         list_01 =self.Treatment_unit.all()
```

Comment: The issue is caused by print function. Inside model's `__str__` method you are trying to print the queryset which in turn calls model's `__str__` method leading to infinite recursion.

Comment: I have removed these two lines and still getting the same error.

Comment: I added a screenshoot of the error lines.

Comment: Can you tell what is `a.name` referring to?

Comment: "name" is a charfield in the Unit model. Meaning Treatment_unit.name

Comment: beause the Treatment_unit is m2m feils I has to create this loop to get the machines name so it will appear as the name of the inline foem.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be causing maximum recursion error. Can you provide broader stacktrace?

Comment: The code seems correct, post your stacktrace

Comment: here you go!...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem is related to this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\mmetwaly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\
django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __init__
   838.           raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
```

I would put a breakpoint there, and run debugger to try to see what's happening.

It would be easier to help you, if you created a minimal set of code that demonstrates the problem, and then post that code in entirety.